# For positive $a_n, b_{n.k}$, when is $\sum_n (a_n \sum_k (-1)^k b_{n.k}) = \sum_k ((-1)^k \sum_n a_n b_{n,k})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A recent question gave a proposed double series for $\pi/4$, in which all inner series were alternating, which was shown to be equal to the Leibniz series for $\pi/4$ if the order of summation was interchanged. So this made me wonder, for positive $a_n, b_{n.k}$, ($n,k \geq 0$) when is the equality $\sum_n (a_n \sum_k (-1)^k b_{n.k}) = \sum_k ((-1)^k \sum_n  a_n b_{n,k})$ justified? Typical absolute convergence criteria may need not apply, e.g. in the case of the Leibniz series identity I saw, where the latter series was equal to $1 - 1/3 + 1/5 + \ldots$ after the rearrangement. So I'm looking for a more general criterion on $a_n, b_{n,k}$ when the identity is guaranteed to hold.